# How do I run selenium webdriver tests using capybara on edge chromium browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have the following code to register my driver for headless chrome mode. However, I am confused on what I need to do to register my driver to run on edge chromium browser. I have edge chromium installed on my Mac machine. I am using selenium webdriver 3.14

```
elsif @browser == 'headless chrome' && !@remote
Capybara.default_driver =:selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,800')
@driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: chrome, options: options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use chrome-based Edge with selenium You need to be using the latest selenium-webdriver 4.x alpha release per this recommendation from Microsoft team:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp

Then you'd need to register your own driver specifying the relevant options and browser as `:edge_chrome` in your Capybara driver initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! i already have an existing suite of tests that run on chrome, headless chrome and firefox using webdriver 3.14. i just want to extend this to run on edge chromium without having to upgrade to webdriver 4.0

Comment: @BhaskarPhukan You can't -- If you want to use edge chromium you have to upgrade to selenium-webdriver 4.0.  It shouldn't break anything in your existing config unless it's really old, and even then it should only be the browser configs not your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ThomasWalpole.